# function to remove all documents that the Age parameter is above 50

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with VSC abd we started with MongoDB.
We got an exercise that we need to remove all documents that the age in those documents are above 50.
For example:

**My code of adding the documents (which works):**
[image: my code of adding the documents (which works)]

I want to know how do I remove (if it's with `DeleteMany()` or other function) them so I'll be left with only the one document that his age is below 50.

Comment: So that people can answer your question easier next time, add the code into the question using the code insert button instead of a screenshot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$gt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator

```
emloyees.deleteMany({ age: {$gt: 50}});
```

Comment: @AvivAsher Where in the MongoDB did you not read about operators